# How to use Polymer TemplateBinding library standalone?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, template-engine

> Polymer’s TemplateBinding library extends the capabilities of the HTML
>   Template Element by enabling it to create, manage, and remove
>   instances of content bound to data defined in JavaScript. Although
>   internal in Polymer, it is also useful standalone.

[TemplateBinding](https://github.com/Polymer/TemplateBinding) is separate library and doesn't depend on Polymer. Therefore theoreticaly it could be possible to use it without polymer.

I cannot found any example how to use this standalone.

For instance, I have such markup

```
<ul>
    <template id="colors" repeat="{{ colors }}">
      <li style="color: {{ color }}">The style attribute of this list item is bound</li>
    </template>
</ul>
```

and json

```
colors: [
          { color: 'red' },
          { color: 'blue' },
          { color: 'green' },
          { color: 'pink' }
        ]
```

I'm looking for something like a function which accepts template and data and returns processed markup.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by standalone? You mean using Polymer outside of a Polymer Web Component?

If so, you can use the autobinding attribute, e.g.

```
<template id="colors" repeat="{{ colors }}" is="auto-binding">
```

This will allow Polymer to see your template in the Light-DOM (everywhere on the page)

Here is a working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lm7tgbLo/

HTML Code:

```
<script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/polymer.min.js"></script>

<ul>
    <template id="colors" repeat="{{color in colors}}" is="auto-binding">
      <li style="color: {{ color }}">The style attribute of this list item is bound</li>
    </template>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function (e) {

    document.getElementById("colors").colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'pink'];

});
```

Comment: [TemplateBinding](https://github.com/Polymer/TemplateBinding) is separate library and doesn't depend on Polymer. Therefore theoreticaly it could be possible to use it without Polymer. I'm looking for something like a function which accepts template and data and returns processed markup.

Comment: Well in this case, you can just use one of the examples. https://github.com/Polymer/TemplateBinding/blob/master/examples/how_to/bind_to_text.html

Answer (score -2):

If your just looking for a good template based UI library. I recommend RactiveJS.
https://ractive.js.org/

Its very easy to get started.

**Template**

```
<p>{{greeting}} {{name}}!</p>
```

**JS Code**

```
var ractive = Ractive({
  target: output,
  template: template,
  data: { greeting: 'Hello', name: 'world' }
});
```